# java.sql.SQLException: The method 'rollback' can't be called when a global transaction is active

Tags: java, oracle, transactions

I want to use java invoke a oracle store procedure to return OracleResultSet, the store procedure have execute delete, insert and select operate(involves two tables). I set auto commit false and when execute commit() occur the error like the Title. 
The code like below:

```
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        resultSet = getResultByInvokeSP(conn);
        conn.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
after commit use
conn.setAutoCommit(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove your calls to setAutoCommit() and commit(). The error suggests you have another framework which is handling your transactions for you.

Comment: @Seven What was solution in the end?

Comment: I will to solve today and share the result no matter successful or not

Comment: Finally, I setAutoCommit false and not commit, but i not sure when close the connection whether commit the transaction.